# jQuery - cannot select third child element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

As mentioned in the title, jQuery does not select 3rd child for some reason. This problem is not occurring when I target first and second child element. I want to hide a paragraph which starts with "Gift Aid legislation..."

Is there any way to sort it?

HTML

```
<div class="pmpro_checkout-fields custom">
    <p>
        You have selected the <strong>Non-Member</strong> membership level.
    </p>

    <p>Need Text</p>

    <div id="pmpro_level_cost">
        <p>The price for membership is <strong>£0.00</strong> now.</p>
    </div>
    <br>
    <span style="margin-top: -25px; display: block">
        Details required on this form will also appear in the Directory Listing. Please read below. *Information required
    </span>
    <hr>
    <h3>Gift Aid</h3>
    <p>Gift Aid legislation allows us to reclaim 25p of tax on every £1 that you give on your subscription and additional donations. It won't cost you any extra.</p>
    <input type="checkbox" id="gift_aid" name="gift_aid" value="1">
    <label class="pmpro_normal pmpro_clickable" for="gift_aid">
        Allow Gift Aid to be collected?
    </label>
    <hr>

</div>
```

Jquery

```
$( ".pmpro_checkout-fields h3" ).hide();
$(".pmpro_checkout-fields p:nth-child(3").hide();
```

Comment: Apart from the syntax error: The third child of your container element is not a paragraph, it is the div with ID `pmpro_level_cost`. Since you explicitly demanded that the `:nth-child(3)` element you are looking for is also of the element type `p`, of course this finds nothing. And what you actually want, is [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

Comment: I've submitted an edit reformatting your HTML that should hopefully clarify what CBroe is saying. Additionally, you're missing a closing parenthesis inside the quotes on your second line of Javascript, which would  make it find nothing even after you fix the fact that it's looking for a 3rd P element that doesn't exist.

Comment: Why don't you just use `>` to refer for children and, `eq()` that's will give it to you `$(".pmpro_checkout-fields > p").eq(2).hide()`

Comment: @Tom_evok, if one of the provided answers solved your problem, don't forget to accept it--you will get reputation towards unlocking more privileges, as will the answerer.

Answer (score 0):

$(".pmpro_checkout-fields p:nth-child(3").hide();
I guess there is syntax problem
$(".pmpro_checkout-fields p:nth-child(3)".hide();

Comment: Explain your answer and put your code in a code block please.

Comment: Hi,
I tried your solution, but it still does not select the third p element.

Comment: $(".pmpro_checkout-fields p:gt(3)").hide();  you can try that way

Answer (score 0):

First, the method Cbroe mentioned in the comments will get you working:

```
$(".pmpro_checkout-fields p:nth-of-type(3)").hide();
```

However, long term, I do not recommend this approach (manual indexes of element positions in a form), as it is fragile. As soon as you add another `<p>` element before the target, things break. If you refactor it, things could break silently. A more standard way would be to surround the elements that should disappear in a div or span with an ID, then target that ID in the jQuery, so that it will *always* work as long as you don't change the ID:

HTML snippet:

```
<div class="pmpro_checkout-fields custom">
    ...
    <hr>
    <div id="giftAid">
        <h3>Gift Aid</h3>
        <p>Gift Aid legislation allows us to reclaim 25p of tax on every £1 that you give on your subscription and additional donations. It won't cost you any extra.</p>
        <input type="checkbox" id="gift_aid" name="gift_aid" value="1">
        <label class="pmpro_normal pmpro_clickable" for="gift_aid">
            Allow Gift Aid to be collected?
        </label>
        <hr>
    </div>

</div>
```

jQuery snippet to replace the two you have:

```
$("#giftAid").hide();
```

This is also a far more readable and maintainable approach. I am, of course, assuming your ultimate goal is to hide the gift-aid section entirely based on some logic. but if you really only want the header and P element hidden, just move the others outside the div tag with the "giftAid" id.